# How to solve $(16800)(1.1)^{n-1} = (18600)+ (1200)(n-1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic-progressions

$$(16800)(1.1)^{n-1} = (18600)+ (1200)(n-1)$$
Since there is an unknown $n$ as the power, I really can't figure out how to solve this equation. I will be appreciate if anyone is willing to help.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_1 with the generalization to $p^{ax+b}=cx+d$

Comment: you can use a numerical method

Comment: In addition to @gammatester has suggested, you could use numerical methods, such as Newton's method or expand the function $a^x$ using Taylor's theorem to a degree you can solve such as degree 3, however, you would bare an approximation error. One more thing, if you are only interested in the answer and not the method, use an equation plot/graph tool.

Comment: Here is an example of a plot showing roots of: -9.209 and 3.824 https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jdfik1z3fy